# Секундомер в Pythonе

Tags: python, python-3.5

Как реализовать секундомер в питоне?
С таким кодом не всегда ловит одну секунду:

```
from time import time
def sec():
    count = 0
    time_now = time()
    while True:
        a = time() - time_now
        if not a % 1:
            print(count)
            print(a)
            count += 1
sec()
```

Output такой:
`0
7.0
1
10.0
2
16.0
3
17.0`
И вообше всегда разний.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы что-то такое хотели?

```
import time
sec = 0
while True:
    print(sec)
    time.sleep(1)
    sec += 1
```

Comment: да, спасибо
а возможно использовать .sleep для того что б затригерить действие через указаний отрезок времени?

Comment: Что вы хотите, можно подробнее?